Rmark error release.gof(capt.pr) RELEASE NORMAL TERMINATION Error in (x3 + 4):length(out) : argument of length 0
I am trying to run a goodness of fit test in Rmark ready for a POPAN model, the POPAN model runs fine but the GOF test doesn't. I cant find anything on google to help. The error is below.
Here is my code:
WSDinj$Sex<-as.factor(WSDinj$Sex)
WSDinj$Inj_bin<-as.factor(WSDinj$Inj_bin)

#process data for POPAN model, add in predefined time intervals
capt.pr <- process.data(WSDinj,begin.time = 2021, model = "POPAN",
                        groups =c("Sex", "Inj_bin"))

#make design data for capt.pr
capt.ddl<-make.design.data(capt.pr)
capt.ddl

release.gof(capt.pr)

I keep getting this error:
release.gof(capt.pr)
RELEASE NORMAL TERMINATION
Error in (x3 + 4):length(out) : argument of length 0

Please help :)
I have googled, not found anything very helpful

Please provide the outpout of dput(WSDinj) as part of your question, and list out the packages you are using (any lines with library(...)) in order to make your issue reproducible.
